# android mapbox parse error

Tags: android, parsing, mapbox

When I include mapbox sdk in the gradle file using -
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:5.5.0'
I created apk and upload to a private server, download to my mobile and try to install, I get an error - 'There Was A Problem Parsing The Package'

I noticed, due to inclusion of mapbox sdk, overall apk size increase by 14mb and this error occurs. Without this sdk, there is no issue. However if I install through adb command prompt with mapbox included, there is no error and app gets installed successfully.

Can anyone help me to come out of this issue?

Comment: I think this is not mapbox error. this might be cause when you making apk so you just clean project and make a new build.

Comment: ya I tried that many times but still getting issue. If possible, can you include this dependency and replicate the scenario by download and install at your device?

Comment: can you please give me xml code of mapbox ? so might be i will help you

Comment: no need for xml code. just try to add in build.gradle file -  implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:5.5.0' and prepare apk. Transfer the apk to your mobile by downloading or copying but not by playstore and try to install. Please check this scenario.